# Order of Items in a single feature

Tags: lookup-column, feature, site-column, site-definition

Can we set order for items in a single feature?

I was trying to create a site column of type lookup for which the lookup-list should be created first after that only we can create the column. In my case both list and column are in the same feature(list is on top of column).

When i created the site the list in the lookup column was null.

Is there any solution for this issue (apart from adding a feature receiver)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can order the artifacts in a feature.

1. Select the artifacts that are in the feature one at a time and click the <kbd><</kbd> button remove the artifacts.
2. Then add them to the feature by selecting them one at a time and clicking the <kbd>></kbd> button to add them in the order you want.

You can also double click them to add or remove them instead of selecting one and then clicking <kbd>></kbd>/<kbd><</kbd>

Comment: i have tried it...it was not working for me